# couldn't install sonata admin bundle

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

while installing admin bundle through this error :

```html
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.7 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.6 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.5 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.4 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.3 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.2 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.1 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - sonata-project/admin-bundle 2.3.0 requires sensio/generator-bundle ~2.3 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for sonata-project/admin-bundle ^2.3 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/admin-bundle[2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.3.7].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

however I have installed sensio/generator-bundle
what is the problem ? and how I can fix that ?

my symfony is 3.0.1

Comment: Looks like you need to use the development version of the 2.4 release of the SonataAdminBundle as no released version is compatible with Symfony 3.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Answer (score 2):

I've recently encountered this kind of issue during an installation of sonata/admin-bundle.

You can work with the dev dependency until the issue is resolved.
Use `composer require sonata-project/admin-bundle:dev-master`

Maybe the installation will require an update of related packages like sonata/user-bundle, use the version required by the bundle or `@dev` .

Answer (score 1):

Take a look of this post on github https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/3467 and this document about sonata project development state. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fSpS10nzlEj9HE-GdZ-BHcxileEzHwRIzLlNfdNtZ2k/edit#gid=0 . So if you can it's better to keep symfony 2.7 for Sonata Admin integrations, at least by the moment.

Comment: yep , you're right I decided to use symfony 2.7 and I installed admin bundle . Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

Work done by Sonata team for compatibility with Symfony3 but this work is not finish apparently.

And I don't find a 2.4 version of SonataAdminBundle in gitHub or documentation